# Not able to execute firebase init command

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have logged in into firebase.com using my google account. 
Now in command prompt I am doing

```
>firebase init
```

and it keeps on asking me about email and password.
Since I logged into via google , I am not sure what is password for firebase account. I have enabled email and password authentication in my app and added users also but still not able to successfully login via firebase init command.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely using a version of the Firebase command line tools that don't support Google authentication yet. To upgrade, run:

```
npm update -g firebase-tools
```

After that running `firebase login` will pop up a browser window where you complete the Google sign-in.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an interactive flag that you can add that opens the browser and you can log in using your google account/credentials that way:

```
firebase login --interactive
```